# "at first glance" VS "at a first glance"

Tags: difference, grammaticality

The Google [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+a+first+glance%2C+at+first+glance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20first%20glance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20first%20glance%3B%2Cc0) shows *at first glance* is much more frequently used than *at a first glance*.

Furthermore, as in [this link(OALD)](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+caveat&oq=meaning+of+caveat&aqs=chrome..69i57.2304j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=at%20first%20glance), *at first glance* is entered as a stand-alone idiom. So I can conclude *at first glance* is the common one.

However, in terms of grammar, I don't see any problems with *at a first glance* and, rather this feels more correct.

Can I use *at a first glance* instead, and would it be accepted as natural and correct in native-English-speaking societies?

Comment: You _can_ use it, but I think it would always give you away as a non-native speaker.

Comment: you can definitely "have a first glance", but you can't "see something at a first glance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first glance as you said is the stand alone idiom...
but if we use at A first glance the it somehow implies the rest of the sentence be like ..." of something"
Example: at a first glance of morning dawn, we shall move on.

Comment: Thank you. Aha, I got your point. It means that *at a first glance* sounds more specific with a lot of spectrum it can be used outside the meaning of *at first glance*. :)

Comment: @Atrin Noori: You are confusing the words "glimpse" and "glance"!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I know what you mean... I didn't mean if a person see the dawn... I was referring to a poetry like the sun see the earth... you know a kind of literature

Comment: @SmartHumanism Kinda like that :)

Comment: We say, "With the first glimpse of dawn we shall move on": not "At the first glance of dawn..." But as long as you and the OP understand each other... :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian yeah that makes sense, 
So let me see at a first glance... I knew she was mine...
now if we say at a first glance, somehow means at a glimpse or just a brief look to something, I guess we cant use it just as an ordinary sentence

Comment: @Atrin Noori That's right. Although we *can* use glimpse as a verb, it's most commonly used as a noun, in "to catch a glimpse of" for example. There are lots of examples [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/glimpse).